# Installing Ubuntu on a Dell studio xps that won't boot as it is

Tags: dell, dell-studio-xps-16

Apologies if this question has already been asked; I did look.

I was gifted a relatively new (but used, recycled) Dell Studio XPS computer (desktop). I never used it before now. When I turn it on it says:

"no boot device available
sata i not available 
sata ii installed 
sata iii not available
sata iv not available"

From what I have read I understand this to mean there is a drive in there I could theoretically install an operating system to.

I would like to install some version of linux. I am pretty new/inexperienced with this sort of thing and really not super savvy. I have a barely-working mac laptop I can use to research and/or download operating systems and save to usb (if that is a thing). Can anyone point me to how I could get the Dell machine up and running with a linux operating system?

Thanks so much and apologies if I am not asking the question properly!

Comment: There are different *Linux* distributions- we specialize in Ubuntu. Grooveplex's link should point you in the right direction. If you have issues, post your questions on this site *if they're about Ubuntu*.

Answer (score -2):

It seems.. there isn't a hard-disk inside your computer (!!!)... or there isn't any operative system installed (that's fine; don't worry... )

- Check your device: where is the hard disk? If you cannot find any HDD, buy a SSD :P No, you can also buy a cheaper HDD, but SSDs are awesome :)

Download the Ubuntu 16.04 iso from the official website. Build a liveUSB using Rufus from another computer. You must run it on your Dell computer. 
PressF2, F10 or ESC (it depends on the device) , enter the bios, change the boot order, giving priority to your USB. The Secure Boot mode must be deactivated!
Then, run Ubuntu LiveCD ("check disk for defects" and "Try Ubuntu without installing"). Sometimes, you must choose the bootable device from the boot menu again. Read your PC manual or search it in Google.
Once the "try ubuntu without installing" option is selected and active make sure that everything works fine and install Ubuntu. [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Hope it helps...

Comment: It says "sata ii installed" so there might e a disk installed, but without a operation system.

Comment: You can't assume that OP has UEFI, nor can you assume Secure Boot is even enabled.